# xfce4: can the Applications Menu (panel plugin) icon be removed/hidden?

Tags: xfce

I can see in the plugin's config window that the button title can be toggled on or off - but the icon can only be selected.

Can it be removed/hidden/turned off somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two years later, I guess it's time to give an answer here.

> Can it be removed/hidden/turned off somehow?

No, we can't do that with **Application Menu**. The panel plugin is closely integrated and is part of `xfce4-panel` package. Unless you intend to tweak the source code and recompile it yourself, the icon can't be removed easily. There's no relevant setting in `xfce4-settings-editor` either.

As Xfce 4.10, an alternative plugin menu called **Whisker Menu** has been introduced and included in major Linux distributions running Xfce desktop environment. Using this menu, you can display title only (hides the panel button icon) as shown in the screenshot below.

[image: Xfce4 Whisker Menu Options]

With the introduction of **Whisker Menu** in newer Xfce releases, perhaps this also indirectly supports the fact that the icon cannot be removed in **Application Menu** after all.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the icon ("Applications Menu") simply:

- make a right-click on the desired panel
- choose "panel->panel preferences..."
- switch to "items" tab
- remove the "applications menu" entry.
- done!

Comment: This, of course, removes the menu in its entirety.

Answer (score 0):

I could't find a way to hide the icon, but I created a "dummy" 16x16 transparent icon with Gimp... The icon space is still there, but I don't care... Used some spacers to fill the other panel's side and everything looks fine for me.

Comment: Oh, I tried to create a 16x1 transparent icon but the space it uses is the same...